# Getting the database with TFS

Tags: database, tfs

I am using TFS and want to get latest version on another computer. This works fine, but the database is empty after I have, on another PC, updated the database with all of those existing (old) migrations in the migration folder.

So when I update, even adds a new migration after that, I get the database, but it's completely empty of all those existing records (tables).

What is going wrong, and why is the db empty of all those tables, yet, the db structure is intact as it's supposed to be, that is, all the tables with their columns is correct.

I am using TFS with ASP.NET MVC and Entity Framework.

Comment: What's the database are you meaning? The database for your project? This will not be stored in TFS. You need manually restore the database from one machine to another.

Comment: When I think on it for a while, I understand what you say. Because I did not think on that, if you have a db with saved records, that would not follow along the migration from the "migration" folder, if I would "update-database" for those pending migrations, because the structure, tables, columns would be right, but the db has to be empty, because it cannot retrieve those previously saved records.

Comment: Also, how do I make a CR (carriage return I believe it is called) in comments here to make a new empty linebreak (pushing "enter" key)?